# Angular 7 - Cannot read JSON file from assets

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Im trying to reading a JSON config file from my assets in angular project. I have created a Service and calling in App.Module.ts in a  initializeApp function.

my jSON files are in **src/assets/config/** folder

When it starts it shows me in console a Empty Json file "{}".

This is my service.

```
import { IConfig } from "../_model/config";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Injectable()
export class Config {
    static settings: IConfig;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    load() {
        const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.${environment.name}.json`; // ${environment.name} could be 'prod' or  'dev'

        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(jsonFile).toPromise().then((response: IConfig) => {
                Config.settings = <IConfig>response;
                resolve();
            }).catch((response: any) => {
                reject(`Error en archivo de configuracion '${jsonFile}': ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
            });
        });
    }
```

and Config interface if you want check:

```
export interface IConfig {
    config: {
        production: boolean;
    };
    path: {
        url_root: string;
    };
    timeZone: {
        time: number;
    };
}
```

console error

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error en archivo de configuracion 'assets/config/config.dev.json': {}
```

it always goes for Catch and prints error message with anf EMPTY JSON, like if not exists.

If you need more info just tell me.

Comment: What benefit do you expect to get when loading the configuration from there?. For most cases it is better to let angular load it for you https://angular.io/guide/build

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the `"src/assets/config/"` path to the `assets: []` array your angular.json file. Then I think you have to recompile the server.

Comment: I don't know the context of your application, but assets typically aren't the best place to put configuration files. Putting them in assets will basically make them public.

Comment: oi know that but the problem is more than this, the problem is why i cannot read a json file from my assets

Comment: Is not enough whit `"src/assets"` added in my `assets:[]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to step back twice. `../../`

replace

```
const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.${environment.name}.json`;
```

with

```
const jsonFile = `../../assets/config/config.${environment.name}.json`;
```

### Secure Recommention

However, I recommend that you have to place the config inside the `environment` files instead of the `assets` folder because the **environment is secured by the browsers** while assets will be public to anyone.